# Minecraft: How do I load chunks outside of my FOV

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-optifine, minecraft-shader

I’ve been trying to make a 360 photo using world curvature function from a shader pack, which I came across a problem: chunks that are not within the vanilla FOV of the player will not be loaded, which looks horrible on the photo, so is there something that can load all the chunks including ones outside of the FOV, I don’t need ones that loads chunks outside or rendering distance, and I don’t need the ones that updates all the chunks real time, but I do need it to work with shaders

Comment: To clear up some confusion that may come from your wording: the chunks are actually loaded - entities are processed, redstone works, mobs spawn, crops grow - they just aren't rendered client-side. That means all solutions based around chunkloaders, bots etc won't work. It's a renderer issue, not a chunk loader issue.

Comment: OK I didn’t know that, thanks for clarifying. So how do I render theses chunks?